# How does TfidfVectorizer take his arguments?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I would like to understand a bit better how TfidfVectorizer works. I don't understand how one used the subsequent functions like `get_feature_name`

Here is a reproducible example for my question:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

text = ['It was a queer, sultry summer', 'the summer they electrocuted the Rosenbergs',
    'and I didn’t know what I was doing in New York', 'I m stupid about executions',
    'The idea of being electrocuted makes me sick',
    'and that’s all there was to read about in the papers',
    'goggle eyed headlines staring up at me on every street corner and at the fusty',
    'peanut-selling mouth of every subway', 'It had nothing to do with me',
    'but I couldn’t help wondering what it would be like',
    'being burned alive all along your nerves']


tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.7,
                                 min_df= 0.01,
                                 use_idf=True,
                                 ngram_range=(1,2)) 

tfidf_mat = tfidf_vect.fit_transform(text)
print(tfidf_mat)
features = tfidf_vect.get_feature_names()
print(features)
```

In this example, I thought that my object `tfidf_vect` was defining all the parameters I want for my application of `TfidfVectorizer`, which I then apply to `text`, to obtain the results in the object `tfidf_mat`.

I don't understand then why, to extract additional information of my tfidf analysis, I apply functions to the object `tfidf_vect` and not to `tfidf_mat`.

How does the command `tfidf_vect.get_feature_names()`  know that this is to be applied to `text`, if that wasn't specified in its definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `tfidf_vect.get_feature_names()` works because `tfidf_vect` is an instance of the class `TfidfVectorizer`. This class has certain attributes (see the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)). These attributes can change after calling methods of the class, such as the method `fit_transform`. Now, `get_feature_names` has access to the same attributes of the class instance as the `fit_transform` method. You might want to read more about [classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html), methods, attributes and such.

So: `tfidf_mat` simply holds the return value of `fit_transform()` (which is a sparse matrix of (n_samples, n_features)). After you call `fit_transform()`, `tfidf_vect`'s attributes are changed, which can be accessed by any method of that class instance (so also by `get_feature_names()`).